# How to GET the item just created by the POST

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I successfully managed to GET data by axios, now I need to get data by Axios which was just created by POST method. Here is my code:

```
  data() {
    return {
      showModal: false,
      info: null,
      percentage: 0,
      selected_item: {
        id: 0,
        bill_number: 0,
        date: "",
        user_id: 0,
      },
    };
  },
```

```
    getNewDeal() {
      axios.post("http://localhost:8080/bills", {
        bill_number: 108,
        date: "",
        user_id: 7,
      });
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:8080/bills")
        .then((response) => (this.info = response.data._embedded.bills));
      this.info[this.info.length - 1].id = this.selected_item.id;
      console.log(this.selected_item.id);
    },
```

> console.log(this.selected_item.id); returns 0 it should return something like 69843, id is autogenerated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POST api call should create the item and then return the ID of the newly created item. Then you can do the following.

```js
getNewDeal() {
    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/bills", {
      bill_number: 108,
      date: "",
      user_id: 7,
    }).then((response) => { // This response should have the ID of the newly created item, this should be set in the POST api call after item create.
      this.selected_item.id = response.data.id // I dont know your response object but get the ID from the response.
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:8080/bills")
        .then((response) => {
          this.info = response.data._embedded.bills;
          this.info[this.info.length - 1].id = this.selected_item.id;
          console.log(this.selected_item.id);
        });
    })
  }
```

I would also think you should have a GET call for a single item if all you need is the single row. `http://localhost:8080/bills/{id}`

Comment: Sorry but I'm kinda new to this what does response .id represents, since the object on my API has 4 values, id(which is autogenerated), bill_number, date, and user_id. If I try the exact code you gave me it says undefined in the console log. Also, I would get only one item but I do not know its id, so I don't know which id to get.

Comment: What do you get when you console log response after the post request?

Comment: I got the whole object,  seems like POST request passed successfully!, But when I print ID later it says its undefined.
```
data: Object { id: 667005, bill_number: 7, user_id: 777777, … }
```

Comment: The exact response has Object text in there?

Comment: okay I solved it, I need to add data before id, so it goes like this this.selected_item.id = response.data.id, edit your answer so I can approve it, tnx!
And yes the response has more objects I just copied the one I think it would be usefull.

Comment: Try this.selected_item.id = response.data.id